# Shopify webhook not redirect to url

Tags: c#, asp.net, shopify, webhooks

I have created a **Order payment webhook** in **shopify**

and given there a url (http://requestb.in/1ciiioc1) in URL textbox,
and now i am making payment of some product on store, but after payment it does not redirected to the given url.

I think it should redirect the user to the given url.

I am able to get the data, but how that page will be trigger so that i can do some work with data.

may be i am on wrong way, it would be better if some one may suggest any link of examples of webhook

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After you register an order webhook, Shopify will make a POST request to your webhook with the order data whenever an order is paid for. This process is invisible to the user and they won't be redirected.